# nginx SSL has too many redirects

Tags: nginx, ssl, configuration, wordpress, fastcgi

We have a Wordpress website hosted on a Nginx VPS and we configured an SSL redirect to force visitors to use SSL.

After creating that redirect we started noticing that the URL of the website started having a '?v=34' parameter, and when we test the website on Pingdom it shows up with 3 redirects between the first connection and the page loading.

[View image of Pingdom result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d52wu.png)

On the server.conf we have two server blocks with the first:

```
server {
 listen 80;
 listen [::]:80;
 server_name URL_SERVER;
 return 301 https://URL_SERVER$request_uri; }
```

The SSL block starts with:

`listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name URL_SERVER;`

Is it possible to remove the two additional redirects and the URL parameter added to the site address?

Comment: Did you change the site's URL in WordPress settings?

Comment: On Wordpress we have the https:// URL without www

Comment: Found the solution, I had on WooCommerce Geo Localization On (with support for page cache) and it didn't work well with fastcgi-cache, that's why the website was redirecting once or twice (it changed with the original location of the client). We changed the store location to the physical address of our shop and everything started working correctly.